# IPersistFile::Save method keeps failing to save the shortcut

Tags: c++, shortcut

I am trying to save a shortcut to my application in the startup folder. It all compiles, but it fails to actually save the game. The error seems to occur at `hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE);`, where hres is set to -2147024891. If that means something specific, I haven't discovered what yet. My code is copied almost verbatim from MSDN, so I'm pretty confused why it isn't working. Perhaps I don't have permission to save a shortcut to the startup folder? Then again, I am also fairly new to all this, so it might be some basic error I am making. I am copying in all my #includes as well in case that is the problem.

Edit:
First, to avoid confusion, this is CLI based C++. 
 
Checking hres for errors is just part of the MDSN code. This is really almost the exact same code from the website example. I have put in breakpoints, which is how I know that hres becomes -2147024891 right after the line `hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE);` is run. 

In case these are wrong, mediaMaestroLocation is set to `"C:\Users\Keith\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MediaMaestro\Debug\MediaMaestro.exe"` and startupDestination is `"C:\Users\Keith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"`. While the exe location looks great, I wonder if it matters that there isn't a \ after the destination folder path. I would have checked it already, but I need to spend a couple minutes figure out how to do it first.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include "objbase.h"
#include <objidl.h>
#include <shlguid.h>
#include <winnls.h>

#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

char startupDestination[MAX_PATH];
char mediaMaestroLocation[MAX_PATH];

DWORD nChars = 0;
BOOL yChars = 0;

HRESULT CreateLink() 
{ 
    CoInitializeEx( NULL, 0 );
    HRESULT hres = 0;
    IShellLink* psl; 

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 

        // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
        // has already been called.
        hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            IPersistFile* ppf; 

            // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
            psl->SetPath(mediaMaestroLocation); 
            psl->SetDescription("Media Maestro"); 

            // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
            // shortcut in persistent storage. 
            hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

            if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
            { 
                WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

                // Ensure that the string is Unicode. 
                MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, startupDestination, -1, wsz, MAX_PATH); 


                // Add code here to check return value from MultiByteWideChar 
                // for success.

                // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
                hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
                ppf->Release(); 
            }
            psl->Release(); 
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return hres; 
}
```

Here is the click event in the UI that calls the function:

```
void settingsLaunchOnStart_Click( Object^ Sender, EventArgs^ e )
   {

       if (settingsLaunchOnStart->Checked == false)
       {
            HRESULT r;
            nChars = GetModuleFileName( NULL, mediaMaestroLocation, sizeof(mediaMaestroLocation) );
            yChars = SHGetFolderPath( NULL, CSIDL_STARTUP, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, startupDestination);
            r = CreateLink();
       }
       else if (settingsLaunchOnStart->Checked == true)
       {

        //code to remove the shortcut
       }
   }
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: sorry but what is hres, have you declared it somewhere?

Comment: `hres is an HRESULT`. The if() check is somewhat pointless, since it was just initialized to 0, which on every run of Windows I've ever seen is synonymous with S_OK, subsequently always evaluating to true. Not your problem, but does answer @computer s question. You may also want to update the question to indicate this uses CLI; not just C++.

Comment: That said, i would start with *all* COM calls being checked for valid return codes. I'm not obtusely familiar with CLI-based C++, but both the string literals you're passing to `SetPath` and `SetDescription` seem odd to me that they're narrow. Is this being compiled with Unicode settings? The value `-2147024891` is synonymous with 0x80070005, the dreaded `E_FAIL`, so something certainly isn't right.

Comment: Wow. I could have sworn it was set to be compiled with Unicode settings, but it was set to multibyte. Is this the source of my problem? I swapped it to unicode and changed the path variables to be `wchar_t` type, but its still not working. I am definitely getting the feeling that this is failing because I am inputting the paths wrong.

Comment: I figured it out. I'll answer my own question when I have working code to post, but it turns out I need to append `"filename.lnk"` onto the `startupLocation` file path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it wasn't enough to name the output folder path, I had to name the file and extension as well. It seems strange to me, considering I don't think I have seen a single other example doing this. Anyway, here is my updated working code:

```
HRESULT CreateLink() 
{ 
    CoInitializeEx( NULL, 0 );
    HRESULT hres = 0;
    IShellLink* psl; 

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 

        // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
        // has already been called.
        hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); //CLSCTX_ALL CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER (void**)&psl (LPVOID*)&psl
        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            IPersistFile* ppf; 

            // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
            psl->SetPath(mediaMaestroLocation);
            psl->SetDescription(L"Media Maestro"); 
            psl->SetIconLocation(mediaMaestroLocation, 0);

            // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
            // shortcut in persistent storage. 
            hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); //(void**)&psl (LPVOID*)&ppf

            if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
            { 
                WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH]; 

                // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 

                hres = _wmakepath_s( wsz, _MAX_PATH, NULL, startupDestination,
                      L"MediaMaestro", L"lnk" );

                hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
                ppf->Release(); 
            }
            psl->Release(); 
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return hres; 
}
```

The addition of `_wmakepath_s` lets me append the name of my program and its extension onto the filepath I got from `SHGetFolderPath`. Once I feed that into the IPersistFile interface it saves as it should.

Answer (score 0):

you have only initialized hres to 0 and then ur checking if it succeded ? u are never realling  declaring it somewhere, and -2147024891 probably means that the variable is not initialized yet.

a wild guess is that it never even reahes the: `hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE);` line and therefore it is not initialized :P try putting out some breakpoints when debugging and maybe use some watches to peek into variables :)

Best regards.

Comment: This is incorrect. `hres` initialized to 0 is synonymous with S_OK, which will eval `SUCCEEDED(hres)` as true. I concur the initial check is pointless, but initializing `hres` isn't the problem (because it is, in fact, initialized).

Comment: I have added in some breakpoints and peaked at the variables already. I probably should have included that information from the start, but I edited my question to answer some of your questions.